# cannot load JSTL taglib within embedded Jetty server

Tags: java, jetty, jstl, taglib, embedded-jetty

I am writing a web application that runs within an embedded Jetty instance.

When I attempt to execute a JSTL statement, I receive the following exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(1,63) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I have the following jars on the classpath

- ant-1.6.5.jar
- ant-1.7.1.jar
- ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar
- core-3.1.1.jar
- jetty-6.1.22.jar
- jetty-util-6.1.22.jar
- jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar
- jsp-api-2.1.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar
- servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
- servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
- standard-1.1.2.jar

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee h77p://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"  
    version="2.4">  
    <display-name>test</display-name>  
</web-app>
```

My code looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<html>  
    <body>  
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>  
        <%= new java.util.Date() %><br/>  
        ${1+2}<br/>  
        <c:out var="${5+9}"/><br/>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

I started my embedded Jetty server like this:

```
Server server = new Server(80);  
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("pig-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war","/");
server.addHandler(context);
server.start();
```

I spent the past two days experimenting with various combinations of jar files, web.xml configurations, and tag library declarations, but to no avail.

How can I get an embedded Jetty server up and running with full JSTL support?

Comment: Where did you find the web.xml file? I'm running embedded Jetty too and have the exact same error, but my project does not contain a web.xml file.

Answer (score 8):

Jetty 8.0, which has pushed as the default when you use jetty:run, has servlet API 3.0. As of that version of the standard, JSTL standard is supposed to be included, and these taglibs cannot be in the webapp classpath, only the standard classpath. However, 8.0.0.M0 forgot to include them.

Specifying 7.1.4.v20100610 helped for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well, but I'd love to know what the real issue is. With jetty 8.x I had no problem running "mvn jetty:run" but "java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war" would not work (which is what I needed to run my web app on heroku). When I switched to 7.x everything seemed to magically come together.

Comment: It (was) just a bug in 8.0M0.

Answer (score 8):

The jstl taglibs must be on **server** classpath. You can add a classloader to current classloader chain before start the server. That's the principle used  by start.jar when it start a jetty server.

```java
ClassLoader currentClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL urlTaglibs = new File(PATH_TO_TAGLIBS).toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader newClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{urlTaglibs},currentClassLoader);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(newClassLoader);

server.start();
```

You should also add it to java start command line argument.

Comment: +1 For *a solution* : this question repeats something like 10 times in SO and all the suggested solutions (add explicitly jstl JAR to the META-INF\MANIFEST.MF, removed colliding servlet JARs etc) simply don't work. Thank you Arsouille !

Comment: Arsouille, in the above, what would the value be for your placeholder "PATH_TO_TAGLIBS" - how can I find "PATH_TO_TAGLIBS" ?

Answer (score 5):

> - jstl-1.2.jar
> - standard-1.1.2.jar

This collides. Remove the `standard-1.1.2.jar`. You should use `standard-1.1.2.jar` **only** with `jstl-1.1.2.jar`. Since JSTL 1.2 the standard JAR has been merged into JSTL JAR, resulting in a single `jstl-1.2.jar` file.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! However, after this change the issue persists.

Comment: Ensure that you haven't extracted any JSTL JAR file and included under each its TLD files in the classpath or definied anything in `web.xml`. Also ensure that you haven't placed/duplicated the JSTL JAR file(s) somewhere else, e.g. in `Appserver/lib` or `JRE/lib`. To install JSTL basically all you need to do is to place the JAR file in classpath (e.g. `/WEB-INF/lib`) and declare the taglib in top of JSP file. That should be it. Really nothing more needs to be done, else it will collide somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

@Drew
Thanks Drew. It works.I had been googling for this and end up here.What my mistake was :
I was using

```
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                     <version>1.1.2</version>
                     <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
```

I changed it from above to

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
             <version>1.2</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and it got working. Also I was using jstls dependency which I removed.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem on Jetty 7, 
I solved it by enabling Jetty to search for TLD:

I did it by setting an attribute on the context:

```
Server server = new Server(80);  
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("pig-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war","/");
context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", 
    ".*/.*jsp-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/.*jsp-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs[^/]*\\.jar$");
server.addHandler(context);
server.start();
```

Refer to http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP#Using_JSTL_Taglibs_for_Jetty_7.x_and_8.x
for further details.

On my project (using maven), I have standard TLDs are on the JAR "org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v2011120803.jar" and theoretically it would be enough to use as value for ContainerIncludeJarPattern the following pattern:

```
".*/org\\.apache\\.taglibs\\.standard\\.glassfish-1\\.2\\.0\\.v201112081803\\.jar"
```

It actually works and it is a confirmation of where do jetty found the tag libs, but I've preferred to leave the previous pattern which I found on the wiki.eclipse.org page linked above.

It may be required to extend the pattern if you want to include custom tag libs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found out that `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` is regarded as the single system URI and all taglib definitions that try to define it are ignored (but when referenced, an error occurs anyway).

I used the following before starting the Jetty and now it works:

```
try {
    Field f = TldScanner.class.getDeclaredField("systemUris");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    ((Set)f.get(null)).clear();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not clear TLD system uris.",e);
}
```

Comment: How in the name of Hades... this did it, it fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two step：

1）add annotation support for the server

//Enable parsing of jndi-related parts of web.xml and jetty-env.xml, #server is

```
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

2) add the follow attribute to the WebAppContext

```
context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-.*\\.jar$");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml, try changing **"h77p://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"** to start with "http://" and see if that fixes the error.

However, that may not be the underlying cause, since I had that same error when using jetty-maven-plugin and JSTL taglib header in my JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

> PWC6188: The absolute uri:
>   http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
>   cannot be resolved in either web.xml
>   or the jar files deployed with this
>   application

I'm using an out-of-the-box Spring MVC template from SpringSource Tool Suite, so am not sure why the Maven plugin for Jetty chokes on it.

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
         <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
     <repository>
       <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
       <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
       <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
       <layout>default</layout>
     </repository>
</repositories>
```

And only javax.servlet:jstl:1.2 is listed in my POM's dependencies, since it now obsoletes taglibs:standard:1.1.2, which was a suggestion given above.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problems. I fixed it by adding the below code:

```
public static final String[] TLD_JAR_NAMES = new String[]{"sitemesh", "spring-webmvc", "shiro-web", "springside-core"};
...
JettyFactory.setTldJarNames(server, TLD_JAR_NAMES);
```

Maybe you can try it. Please replace TLD_JAR_NAMES with your real TLD Jar names.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following code I got rid of the problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.29</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using jetty-runner 8.