# Jetty 8 standalone doesn't detect jstl taglib jar

Tags: jstl, jetty

I have started a simple servlet 3.0 project which contains now a jsp page where I am using the jstl core tags. If I'm starting this with mvn jetty:run I can see the output properly calculated. But if I'm packaging the project as a war and deploy it into a standalone jetty server, it fails for the same page with

```
PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I have checked that jstl-1.2.jar is in the war under WEB-INF/lib. What did I miss else?

I am using jetty 8.1.3.v20120416 in maven and the standalone installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely related to [cannot load JSTL taglib within embedded Jetty server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151075/cannot-load-jstl-taglib-within-embedded-jetty-server)

Make sure you don't have duplicate jars present in your WEB-INF/lib  especially the servlet-api, jstl, and standard jars.